# How do you get a minimum value from a binary search tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I have created a Binary search class but i am struggling to create a minimum function to help find the smallest value in a binary tree.

```
class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self, new_data):
        if new_data == self.data:
            return
        elif new_data < self.data:
            if self.left == None:
                self.left = BinarySearchTree(new_data)
            else:
                self.left.insert(new_data)
        else:
            if self.right == None:
              self.right = BinarySearchTree(new_data)
            else: 
              self.right.insert(new_data)

    def create_string(self,spaces):
        info = ' ' * spaces + str(self.data)
        if self.left != None:
            info += '\n(l)' + self.left.create_string(spaces + 4)
        if not self.right == None:
            info += '\n(r)' + self.right.create_string(spaces + 4)
        return info

    def __str__(self):
        representation = self.create_string(0)
        return representation

    def get_left(self):
        return self.left

    def get_right(self):
        return self.right

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

def minimum(tree):
    if tree.left:
        return minimum(tree.get_left)
    else:
        return tree.get_left
```

So i wrote the minimum function but for some reason it always returns a Nonetype error. Does anyone have an idea how to get_left on the binary tree until there are no more nodes

Comment: `else: return tree.data` should fix it

Comment: return minimum(tree.get_left())

Comment: It still returns a none type, even after replacing with the tree.get_left()

Answer (score 1):

Non-recursive solution

```
def minimum(tree):
    while tree.left is not None:
        tree = tree.left
    return tree.data
```

Comment: It would be more pythonic to write: `while tree.left:` - the part `is not None` is redundant.

Comment: What I find weird is even though I have defined the 'get_left()' in the calss, when I call on it in my minimum functioin, nothing shows up?, or just a nonetype

Comment: @Matthew when you `return tree.get_left` or `return minimum(tree.get_left)` you do not call `get_left`. Instead you return the function or pass it to `minimum`, not its result. Remember, python functions are objects that you can return from a function or pass them to a function.

Comment: Ah,I understand. Does it mean then, that the function is not being returned if the Nonetype error appears?

Comment: @Matthew I think actually you should see `AttributeError` with something like `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'left'`

Comment: @Alik I looked up attribute error on google and you are right. Would you also know why this is the case?

Comment: @Matthew It happens because you pass the function. The function has no `left` attribute. To prevent this from happening call `get_left` by adding `()`

Answer (score 1):

If there is no `tree.left` you should return `tree`:

```
def minimum(tree):
    if tree.left:
        return minimum(tree.get_left)
    else:
        return tree
```

As you mentioned in your question, since there is no `tree.left` returning `tree.get_left` will return `None`

Comment: The thing i am stuck on is that i defined get_left() in my class, but in my minimum function it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @Matthew when you call get_left you should use brackets: `tree.get_left()` in your example you're doing: `tree.get_left`

Answer (score 1):

```
def minimum(tree):
    if tree.left:
        return minimum(tree.get_left)
    else:
        return tree
```

First if statement checks tree.left = None and hence returning tree.get_left returns None.